# What is the size of an RValue reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

What is the size on the stack of an RValue reference?

For example in a case such as this:

```
struct A { /* ... */ };
A getA()
    {
        A temp; 
        return temp;  
    }
A&& a1 = getA() ;
```

I understand that the compiler extends the lifetime of the temporary to match the lifetime of a1, so I assume a1 must take up the size of an A object on the stack.

what about in the case of sending an object to a function that gets an RValue reference parameter?
For example in this case:

```
void f1(A&& a) {

}
```

What is the size of what is passed on the stack? Just a pointer, or the size of A?

Comment: Why do you wonder? Is there a problem with rvalue references when you pass them? Or is this just plain curiosity?

Comment: Why don't you try to use `sizeof` in the `f1` function? If you use it, you'll get the size of `A`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It was a question raised by some of my students.

Comment: It's really an implementation detail, so to figure out what is really passed you have to examine the generated machine code. Besides that, the most common way to implement lvalue references is by using pointers. Not sure about rvalue references though, it could very likely be implemented using pointers as well, or the compiler might pass objects. It might even depend on a case-by-case basis. Like I said, examine the generated machine code to know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

In general in C++, references act as aliases for other objects and as such occupy no space at all. The compiler will try hard to elide them entirely. This is usually easy to do because a reference cannot be "reassigned" to refer to something else.

But sometimes references need to be stored for a longer period of time (e.g. as class members) or passed around at run-time (e.g. as function arguments). In these situations references are generally implemented as pointers. So e.g. on a 64-bit machine they would occupy either 1 register or 8 bytes on the stack (remember that first N function arguments are generally passed via registers, refer to the platform ABI for details).

There is no difference between rvalue- and lvalue-references in this regard.

Comment: Good answer. I would be interested in what happens if you call a dll-function with an rvalue reference. How does the compiler prepare the assembly for that call?

Comment: Good explanation. Minor point. A change was made in c++20 and now references can be reassigned. But only references in objects as part of a full object re-assignment. Top level references still can't be reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

It has no size at all.

An rvalue-reference is a *value category* and not a value itself. It's more like a concept that the compiler can base certain assumptions on than it is a concrete value.

The same is actually true for lvalue-references. The standard never said that those must always be implemented as pointers, in fact the compiler is free to emit assembly that is completely free of pointers as long as the underlying semantics of the concept "reference" are fulfilled. So you can't actually even say that an lvalue-reference is machineword-sized.

If you look at the definition of `std::move()` you'll find that essentially what happens is that the value category of whatever you put in is just switched to "rvalue reference" without performing any logic. The compiler now has to keep the value category of this newly converted object in mind to select the right overloads for an eminent function call. The function itself will then also base some logic of the "rvalue-ness" of the passed parameter, but in essence the "rvalue-ness" never materializes down to actual machine code in any case, it's all handled by the compiler to create an abstract model of your program which allows it to produce efficient assembly.

Compare the following code and assembly:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

auto __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo(std::string&& tmp)
{
    printf("%s", tmp.data());
}

int main()
{
    foo("Hello");
}
```

Assembly:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%s"
foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&):
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        jmp     printf
main:
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 32
        lea     rax, [rsp+16]
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+20], 111
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16], 1819043144
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 5
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+21], 0
        call    foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()
        add     rsp, 32
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        ret
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

From the QWORD PTR's you can see that the compiler arranges a temporary string object on the stack. It then calls `foo()` wich *assumes* a certain stack layout in which it will find the string, hence it never bothers to materialize it within the stack frame of `foo()` but rather uses the data in the `main()` stackframe.

Comment: Nomenclature problems. Both lvalue references and rvalue references are lvalues. rvalues don't have names. And `std::move()` doesn't produce an rvalue reference. It produces an xvalue which is a type of rvalue.

Comment: @doug regarding nomenclature, wouldn't (int&&)(5) be both an rvalue reference and an rvalue?

Comment: @GonenI No, just an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get sneaky to determine the size of a reference and it's not even possible for a top level reference. The reason is that there is no way to find the address of a top level reference. But if you cloak a reference in a class it suddenly has to exist as a kind of anonymous object within the class. And now you can find it's size and "address" by taking the address of the object it's hiding in.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int&& rri;
};

int main()
{
    A a{ 42 };
    std::cout << a.rri << ", size=" << sizeof(a) << ", address=" << &a << '\n';
    // Output on my system: 42, size=8, address=0000002173EFF9B8
}
```

Comment: what's the size of a on your system without rri?

Comment: @GonenI, 1 of course. Top level empty classes are padded with a byte so that individual instances don't have the same address.